# Paypal throws empty response while send multiple items

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working from last couple of days on same issue. Getting empty response while sending multiple items. But, for single payment, I am getting Array values. Can you please check the below code and let me know any changes required.

Test.php
..............

```
 <?php 
  $cur_dir='http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>

  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxxxxxx@gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="US">

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="beach ball">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">

  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="towel">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $cur_dir.'/test1.php'; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $cur_dir.'/test.php'; ?>">
  <input type="image" value="submit" src="images/byunow.jpg" alt="submit Button" >



              </fieldset>

          </form>
```

Test1.php           returns Empty value
.................

```
   <?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to enable the Payment Data Transfer feature for the seller account - see: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

you can then take the returned data to establish a secure connection to paypal in order to retrieve payment details.

However, please bear in mind that the buyer won't hit the return URL 100% of the time - so you will want to rely on IPN (See: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) for processes like updating an order status.

IPNs are sent to the "notify_URL" as soon as a new transaction arrives on the account.

Comment: @ Paypal_Martin, Yes i am doing the same way which you said. This is working fine for Single payment i.e Item_name. but not for item_number_1.

Comment: right, the PDT parameters (you at least need the txn id) will be returned in a GET request by default. You should be able to use RM=2 to specify a POST, but I can't get it to work right now either. Let me get back to you on that

Comment: Yes, U r right. I am getting Mandatory Get params. but I want all the parameters. This is my response string as GET :test1.php?tx=27G7389203644584U&st=Completed&amt=35.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=

Comment: Yes, these are the paramters returned to you. Take the TXN id and then POST it back to PayPal to retrieve the rest of the payment information - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/ just POST cmd=_notify-synch + tx=<TXN#> + at=<YourPDTtoken> to paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr --> As for getting the data returned via POST, it looks like RM is not being respected right now.

Comment: Thanks for your research and response. Upto some level it is working fine. After sent back to paypal with Txn id , It is not redirecting to my website. Response Printed at paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr like Sucess..etc.. i.e auto redirection to my website is not working. Can you please suggest.

Comment: Auto Return needs to be enabled under https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments - also, if you test using "Guest Checkout", the auto return is disabled (that's why I mentioned that buyers won't hit the return URL 100% of the time), so the buyer will have to manually click on your return link. Also note that the timeout for the auto-return is hard-coded to 10 seconds.

Comment: I set Auto Return Enabled in Sandbox. For first time Paypal Auto return working fine with out manual action. The problem is when we resend TXN ID to Paypal for Complete details, then it structs at Paypal webpage and shows all details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41658/discussion-between-kishore-and-paypal-martin)